# $\chi^2$ feature selection using large words classes in NLP

Tags: chi-squared-test, feature-selection, natural-language, contingency-tables

As described [here](http://blog.datumbox.com/using-feature-selection-methods-in-text-classification/) and [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/chi-square-feature-selection-1.html), $\chi^2$ feature selection can be used in order to filter a set of words that have a low dependency with a given class C.

In my case, I have a corpus of documents where each is assigned a sentiment (positive or negative). After pre-processing my text—stopwords, stemming and removing words that appear in less than 1% or in more than 50% of my documents—I define my positive class as any word contained in a document with positive sentiment and similarly for the negative one.

I then use the $\chi^2$ filtering approach with contingency tables.
Below is an example of for word 'increase' and my positive class:

[image]

The problem I have is that my 2 classes are quite broad (hence the $\chi^2$ filtering!) and there's always a word from each class in any document. Which makes my $N_{01}$ and $N_{00}$ equal to 0 for all the words.

The denominator of my $\chi^2$ formula (below) is then systematically equal to 0 because of the 4th term.

$$
\chi^2(D, t, c) = \frac{N\left(N_{11}N_{00} - N_{10}N_{01}\right)^2}
{(N_{11}+N_{01})(N_{11}+N_{10})(N_{10}+N_{00})(N_{01}+N_{00})}[4]
$$

Is there something that I'm not doing well?
If not, is there a trick or an alternative I could use to avoid this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Chi-square assumes that you have a large enough expected value of each cell count $k \geq 5$. This means that each cell of the contingency table should have a minimal value of $5$.

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. I've edited your answer to fix the typo (there is an edit button below your answer) - it should appear in a few minutes (after that, you may delete your comment since it's no longer needed). By the way, take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).